# Ruby Class: command not found

Tags: ruby

I'm sorry in advance i know a straight code dump is not a good way to ask a question but this is my first Ruby script and i can't even try to debug it because i'm getting weird errors. I am running my script using git and it's just straight broken.. What am i not understanding? Am i missing a gem install or something? Even a pointer to relevant reading would be greatly appreciated.

As is the error i recieve:

```
$ hello.rb
./hello.rb: line 8: class: command not found
./hello.rb: line 10: attr_accessor: command not found
./hello.rb: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./hello.rb: line 11: `  def initialize(name,cash,zip)'
```

and if i move my loop from the bottom to the top:

```
$ hello.rb
./hello.rb: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./hello.rb: line 6: `def main()'
```

hello.rb:

```
#
#
#
#
#
 class Person
        #Attribute accessor methods (accessor=writer+reader)
        attr_accessor :name,:cash,:zip,:credit_card
        def initialize(name,cash,zip)
            @name=name
            @cash=cash
            @zip=zip
            @credit_card=nil
        end
    end
    #Ruby class naming convention: FirstLetterCapCamelCase
    class Account
        attr_accessor :account_name
        #No writer attribute method for balance
        attr_reader :balance
        def initialize(Person)
            time=Time.new
            @key="Kudzu"
            @Person=Person
            @Atm=Atm.new
            #seed the random number generator to get a new random set
            #for each new instance of bank
            srand(time.sec)
            #Ruby naming convention for variables and methods is lowercase this_that
            @name=Person.name
            @balance=nil
            @accounts=nil
            #                                   (#items, initial values)                                                     (ranndom range 100-999)                                          
            @credit_card = {"card_number"=>Array.new(4,1000+rand(9999)),"exp_month"=>time.month,"exp_year"=>time.year+4,"security_code"=>100+rand(999),"zip_code"=>Person.zip, "pin"=>@pin}
            puts("Hello I'm glad you came in here's your new card #{@credit_card[card_number]}")
            while(true)
                puts("Please enter your pin so that i can initialize your card (1234) >> ")
                temp = gets.chomp
                if(temp.is_a?Numeric&&temp.lenth===4)
                    @pin = temp
                    break
                puts("Pin must be a 4 digit number")
            end
            Person.credit_card=@credit_card
            Atm.add_account(Person,credit_card,Base64::encode(key),Account)
            puts("New account created, thanks for signing up #{account_name}!")
        end
        def withdraw(amount, Person, key)
            if(Base64::decode(key)===@key)
                if(@balance>=amount)
                    @balance-=amount
                    Person.cash+=amount
                    puts("Balance after withdraw: $#{this.balance}")
                    return true
                else
                    puts("Insufficient Funds ):")
                    return false
                end
            else
                puts("Access Denied")
                return false
            end

        end
        def deposit(amount, Person, key)
            if(Base64::decode(key)===@key)
                if(Person.cash>=amount)
                    #           Negative amount
                    Person.cash+=amount-amount*2
                    @balance+=amount
                    puts("Balance after deposit: $#{this.balance}")
                    return true
                else
                    puts("Show me the money!")
                    return false
                end
            else
                puts("Access Denied")
                return false
            end

        end
        def transfer(ToAccount, ToPerson, FromPerson, amount, key)
            if(Base64::decode(key)===@key)
                if(withdraw(amount,FromPerson))
                    ToAccount.deposit(amount,ToPerson)
                    return "#{amount} has been transfered from #{account_name}'s account to #{ToAccount.name}'s account. Your remaining balance after this transaction is $#{@balance}"
                end
            else
                puts("Access Denied")
                return false
            end

        end
    end

    class Atm
        @people={}
        @accounts
        @card={}
        @Account
        #Encoding is not encryption to do this: gem install encryptor
        #I didn't take the time to learn how to implement encryption but..
        #Neo "Do you know how to fly this thing?" Trinity "Not yet.."
        @key="Kudzu"
        #Ruby Convention is to use {} for a single line method body
        def add_account(Person,credit_card,key,Account)
            if(Base64::decode(key)===@key)
                @people[credit_card]=Person
                @accounts[credit_card]=Account
                @Account=Account
            else
                puts("Access Denied")
                return false
            end
        end
        #Syntactical Sugar
        def get_pin()
            while(true)
                puts("Ener Your Pin Number or (C)ancel >> ")
                #The method chomp of the object gets returns user input without the trailing /n
                temp=gets.chomp
                if(temp===@card[pin])
                    @Person=@people[card]
                    req_action()
                    break
                end
                if(temp==="C")
                    break
                end
                puts("Didn't catch that try again")
            end
        def start_transaction(card)
            get_pin()
        end

        private
        def deposit()
            puts("How much would you like to deposit >> ")
            temp=gets.chomp
            if(temp.is_a? Numeric)
                @Account.deposit(temp, @Person, Base64::encode(key))
            else
                puts("Didn't catch that try again")
                deposit()
            end 
        end
        def withdraw()
            puts("How much would you like to withdraw >> ")
            temp=gets.chomp
            if(temp.is_a? Numeric)
                @Account.deposit(temp, @Person, Base64::encode(key))
            else
                puts("Didn't catch that try again")
                deposit()
            end 
        end
        def transfer()
            puts("How much would you like to transfer >> ")
            amount=gets.chomp
            if(temp.is_a? Numeric)
                puts("Card number of reciever (1234 5678 9123 4567)>> ")
                temp=gets.chomp
                #gsub = replace all  
                #\s+ = one more more white space characters 
                #m = multiline 
                #strip = remove white space from beg & end
                #split will return the values split by given delimiter
                temp=temp.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip.split(" ")
                Person=@accounts[temp]
                if(Person)
                    @Account.transfer()
                    deposit(@accounts[temp], @people[temp], @Person, amount, Base64::encode(key))
                else
                    puts("We can only transfer to clients of the same bank (incorrect card number)")
                    transfer()
                end
            else
                puts("Didn't catch that try again")
            end 
        end
        def req_action()
            puts("Would you like to (W)ithdraw (D)eposit or (T)ransfer >> ")
            temp=gets.chomp.upcase
            temp=temp.upcase
            #I wonder is it the Ruby convention to not have the when cases indented in the case conditional SublimeText seems to think so
            case temp
            when "W"
                withdraw()
            when "D"
                deposit()
            when "T"
                Transfer()
            else
                puts("Didn't catch that try again")
                req_action()
            end
            while(true)
                puts("Leave Atm (y/n) Another Transaction >> ")
                continue=true
                temp=gets.chomp
                temp=temp.upcase
                case temp
                when "Y"
                    puts("Returning Card")
                    continue=false
                when "N"
                    req_action()
                else
                    "Your fingers are too fat please try again"
                end
                if(!continue)break
            end
        end
    end

    while(true)
        #return list of all instances of class Person in array people
        $people=Person.all_offspring
        $atm=Atm.all_offspring[0]
        puts("would you like to go to the atm (a/r) or register a new account >> ")
        temp=gets.chomp
        temp=temp.upcase
        case temp
        when "A"
            if(people)
                while(true)
                    contine=true
                    puts("Who are you? #{people}")
                    temp=gets.chomp
                    for x in people
                        if(temp===people[x].name)
                            Person=people[x]
                            continue=false
                        end
                    end
                    if(!continue) break
                end
            end
            $atm.start_transaction(Person.credit_card)
        when "R"
            puts("What is your name >> ")
            name=gets.chomp
            money=nil
            zip=nil
            loop do
                done=false
                puts("How much money do you have >> ")
                temp=gets.chomp
                if(temp.is_a?Numeric)
                    money=temp
                    done=true
                    break
                else
                    "Not a number"
                end
            end
            loop do
                done=false
                puts("What is your zip code >> ")
                temp=gets.chomp
                if(temp.is_a?Numeric)
                    if(temp.length===5)
                        money=temp
                        done=true
                        break
                    else
                        puts("invalid length")
                    end
                else
                    puts("not a number")
                end
            end
        else
            "invalid input"
        end
    end
```

Comment: what's `attr.reader :balance` line doing in your code? It should be `attr_reader :balance`. And would you like to explain which line this problem is exactly happening. It seems to be that the code you're showing isn't exactly the same you've got the error for.

Comment: @User089247 yes i realized that mistake but failed to change all the occurrences before posting. It is indeed the same code with from which i am receiving the error for maybe the lines mismatch because i deleted 5 lines of comments from the top. It seems that i am getting an error on the first line class Person (class command: not found).

Comment: Aren't you interpreting this file with bash (or whatever your shell is)? Try `ruby hello.rb` instead of `./hello.rb`

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev Yes, thank you. Sorry for being such a grasshopper.

Comment: BTW, I find the way this code is formatted unreadable. Indentation is inconsistent. No spaces around operators. Not enough new lines between methods. Etc. Take a look at this: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev Thanks! I read over the style guide and after cleaning up my code I found all the missing ends and improper formatting and it really saved my program. This was giving me an killer headache and just creating some white space made all the difference in the world. Never again. Also i was wondering is there perhaps a better section under which i should have posted this question on stack? Perhaps peer review since it's not really a direct question?

Comment: @spintron: there is a site specifically for code reviews: http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

These are error messages from some shell, not Ruby. What you have there is a Ruby script. You need to run your Ruby script with Ruby. Your shell doesn't understand Ruby, it only understands its own language.

Answer (score 1):

put
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

at the top of your script  (assuming your using linux )